# Delete or modify number of invoice in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, invoice

I want to modify the single number of the invoice in Magento (not modify the start increment ID).

Or alternatively delete only the invoce (not also the order), if after i can recreate the invoice from the single order in backoffice and consequently I'll have the correct number in the invoice.

I want to renumber like this:

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to have the invoice `increment_id` match the one of orders?

Comment: The number of order isn't important for me, i want only to renumber the the invoice because i want to start from the invoice number 9. Now this isn't possible for me because the 009 is yet present, the present number was: 04 05 06 07 08 09 010 011. I want only 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 and start form 09 for the successive invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login to your database via phpMyAdmin (google how to do that) and issue:

```
update sales_flat_invoice_grid set increment_id='10300000314' where increment_id='103000003';

update sales_flat_invoice set increment_id='10300000314' where increment_id='103000003';
```

where 103000003 - old invoice number, 10300000314 - new invoice number

do that for every invoice number you want to change.

backup DB just in case.